# Edit standard keyboard with custom extension swift

Tags: swift, ios8, customization, uikeyboard

Is it possible to use a copy of the default-keyboard to work with custom extensions? And if yes, how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

No.

(Also I'm pretty sure this question's been asked and answered here already but I'm not managing to find the duplicate right now.)